# Выбор серверной ОС

Tags: веб-сервер, сервер

Подскажите какую ОС (из винды/линуха/фриБСД) выбрать для дальнейшей веб-разработки и администрирования. Читал хорошие отзывы про OpenSuse, какое ваше мнение о ней?

Comment: Со всем вышесказанным согласен. Надо знать для чего будите использовать. Хм, а ведь SLED Suse (на мой взгляд самый достойный вариант Suse сервер) разве не платный?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала стоит более точно сформулировать вопрос, ибо "Серверная ОС" понятие растяжимое.Если смотреть поверхностно, то по большому счёту нет смысла выбирать между линукс и виндовс (разве что за винду денег придётся отдать). Весь софт по созданию веб-серверов, доменов и DNS доступен на обеих платформах, и на обеих платформах он поддерживается производителем. Если вы желаете тонко настраивать свои сервер, то конечно же линукс (но там придётся быть очень осторожным, линукс не любит помарки в конфигах).

Comment: Против винды не чего не имею против, но склоняюсь к выбору линуха. Выбрал для себя Дебиан и OpenSUSSE, что скажете о моём выборе? На сервер планирую поставить Апач, Мускул, ПХП (возможно Руби), Яву, SVN, FTP.

Comment: Лично мне по душе OpenSuSe. Вы можете загрузить себе DVD версию. Во время установки в разделе с софтом поставите галочку напротив того совта, который вам нужен (веб-сервер так и подписан "веб-сервер"). Так же в OpenSuSe есть Yast, это невероятно мощный инструмент для сисадмина. Потратив 3-4 дня на его изучение, Вы сможете очень быстро и без каких либо синтаксических помарок редактировать конфиги вашей системы. Yast очень удобен, в том случае если Вас не интересуют пальцы козой и фразы типа "Я крутой линуховод и всё правлю руками в тексте".

Comment: Пальцы козой в любом случае могу загнуть, перейдя с Yast`а в консольку :) Можете немного по поводу Дебиан рассказать: прочитал, что на нём есть много дистрибутивов, какой из них (например Ubuntu Server Edition) предпочтительней выбрать или же чистый Дебиан ставить? И вопрос про OpenSuse: на сервере 4Гб оперативки, имеет ли смысл ставить 64-битную версию и будут ли какие то проблемы (с софтом и т.п.) при использовании этой версии операционки?

Comment: Не находил не одной программы которой не было бы на x64. Я не пользовался ничем кроме SuSe (как серверное решение), поэтому ничего сказать не могу. Вы можете установить х32 а потом компилировать свежее ядро с PAE, и будет у вас 2 ядра :) И можно будет экспериментировать ;)

Comment: Ок, всё ясно, буду пробовать openSUSE х86_64. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Занимаюсь веб-разработкой и администрированием. Для серверов (любых, кроме контроллеров домена) использую только Linux. Какие дистрибутивы? - большой разницы нет: ubuntu, centos, gentoo (разница только при настройке), но обязательно без графической оболочки - так стабильнее. Сервер должен быть сервером, поэтому всегда лучше разделять функции сервера и рабочей станции на разные машины. Все требуемое вами заработает на любом linux. Для кодинга инструменты есть и для linux, и для win. А вот если будете заниматься еще и web-дизайном - полноценных аналогов Photoshop и CorelDraw я пока не видел, поэтому дизайнить в MS Windows удобнее (если не рассматриваем MacOS, конечно). Считаю хорошим вариантом: рабочая станция для кодинга и дизайна - под Windows, а сервер - под Linux, который для начала можно развернуть на виртуалке, затем перенести на VPS-хостинг или выделить под это отдельную машину.

Answer (score -1):

Solaris 11

Comment: Я так понимаю вы с ним работаете. Почему отдали ему предпочтение?

Comment: Выбор ОС от многих условий. Если у Вас просто Apache + php + MySQL, то подойдёт любая nix-система и чем меньше там будет мусора тем лучше. А если Вы решили сделать что-то поинтересней, выбрать в качестве сервера приложений Weblogic, например, а БД Oracle, то и ОС нужно подобрать соответственно Solaris. А если вам необходима, например, повышенная сохранность данных, то это могут обеспечить только транзакционные файловые системы, такие как ZFS. А есть на в солярисе и FreeBSD. Ну а если Вы работаете с ASP, тут без винды не обойтись.

Comment: Можно правда ещё всё это совместить, установив например на сервере гипервизор такой как VMWare ESXi.

Comment: На данный момент мне сервер нужен больше в учебных и личных целях, в повышенной сохранности и журналировании каждого шага нет необходиомсти. Рассказали популярно, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: ZFS не журналируемая файловая система, а именно транзакционная. Состояние файловой системы можно зафиксировать мгновенно, кстати яблочная Time Mashine основывается на ZFS.